# Jquery addClass does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am starting with Jquery and i had this problem. I want click in the button send and have the input's border in red.

HTML CODE

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Put your name" id="name"/>
<input type="submit" value="send" id="send"/>
```

Javascript code

```
var name = document.getElementById('name');
$("#send").click(onClick);

           function onClick() {
               $("#name").addClass("error");
           }
```

CSS STYLE

```
.error{
    border-color:red;
}
```

If I put the .addClass out of the function click works and I don't know where is the problem?

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: send is not defined`: http://jsfiddle.net/4b7Ug/ You probably want to remove `onclick="send"` from the HTML code.

Comment: So, not only did you revert the formatting of the question and make it harder to read again, your code change makes all the answers obsolete and people wasted their time. Why did you change `onClick` to `id`? What is the code you actually have?

Comment: i correct that not changes in the result

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question with the solutions you get from the answers, because now the answers don't make sense anymore. And as you can see from the demo, using `id` instead of `onClick` (as you have it in your question now) works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/4b7Ug/3/.

Answer (score 3):

`$("#send").click(onClick);` looks for an item with `id=send`; your button has `value` `send`, which is different. Add `id="send"` to your `<input type="submit" value="send" onclick="send"/>`

The full HTML code should look like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Put your name" id="name"/>
<input type="submit" value="send" id="send"/>
```

Comment: you are right but it still not working

Comment: @user3192010 This is not working because of the "send" function called.

Comment: i have this                                                       <input type="text" placeholder="Put your name" id="name"/>
<input type="submit" value="send" id="send" onclick="send"/>

Comment: and this                                                           var name = document.getElementById('name');
$("#send").click(onClick);

           function onClick() {
               $("#name").addClass("error");
           }

Comment: i can't understand what is wrong

Comment: @user3192010: Look at the very first comment to your question. That's what's wrong. But since the HTML in your question is different from the one in your comment here, it's difficult to help you now.

Comment: I removed the `onclick="send"` - that was a typo (I need more sleep)

Answer (score 1):

Try using :

```
<input type="submit" value="send" id="send"/>
```

You were using `onclick` attribute to call a `send` fnction which do not exists.
And you where querying a `#send` id which do not exist either. I think you missed a modification when you wrote you JS code.

Comment: Why should the OP use this? What's the problem with the OP's code? Don't just post code, **explain** the problem and the solution (otherwise you are playing the "spot-the-difference" game).

Comment: He was calling a "send" function wich do not exists, and looking for a "#send" selector without any id element linked to it.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and add this information.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" value="send" id="send"/>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#send').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('#name').addClass('error');
    });
});
```

when you click the submit button, you send the form, thats why you should use `e.preventDefault()` .

You should also put your jquery code inside the document.ready function

Comment: Don't just post code, **explain** the problem and the solution.

Comment: @FelixKling my bad, i will. note that he changed some of the error to our answer

Comment: @FelixKling would that do? or can i improve that in a way?

Answer (score 0):

I actualy didn't get your need, but all i understand according to that, use this method

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
  $("#myform").on('submit',function(){onClick();return false;});
});

function onClick() {
   $("#name").addClass("error");   
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Put your name" id="name"/>
    <input type="submit" value="send" id="send"/>
</form>
```

you need to use form tag to make submit button works and to control its working, and also you need to use function on "submit" event so the code can sense that it should have to control form working.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do what you are trying to achieve. Here is a working [js fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/7f2fC/)

```
$("#send").on('click', function(e){
    $("#name").addClass("error");

    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Tips: why are you using native javascript function when using jQuery.

Instead of:

```
var name = document.getElementById('name');
```

you can simply do:

```
var name = $('#name');
```

Hope that helps.